# Magento 1.9 - Abandoned Cart reminder email showing Rupee while user added as Dollar

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, admin-panel, email-reminders, abandoned-cart

We have two **store** in Magento "India" and "Not India". We setup **currency** and it is reflecting at front end for both type of customers.

[image]

The issue is when from admin, we look for Not India customers abandoned cart, then it shows Rupee (Rs.).

[image]

Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Currency Symbol according to Store. you can check the screenshot for how to change the Store in Magento and change the currency symbol accordingly.

Hope it will help you.

[image]